# Vuex doesn't detect actions or mutations but detects getters fine

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to set up Vuex in my Vue app.

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);
import storeData from "./store";

const store = new Vuex.Store(
   storeData
)

Vue.component('home', require('./components/Home.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store
});
```

store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const state = {
    members: [],
};

export const getters = {
    members: state => () => {
        return state.members;
    }
};

export const actions = {
    async getMembers({ commit, state, dispatch }){
        const res = await this.$axios.get('getMembers');
        const { data } = await res;
        commit('setMembers', data);
    }   
};

export const mutations = {
    setMembers(state, members){
        state.members = members;
    },
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
});
```

Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Home</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        {{ members }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions, mapMutations } from "vuex";
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.getMembers();
        },
        computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            members: 'members'
        })
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions({
            getMembers: 'getMembers'
        })
        }
    }
</script>
```

The homepage is showing the "members" getter with on issues. I see it in developer tools as an empty array and if I set it to anything else it will show it. However it is not detecting the actions or mutations if I try to make a mutation. The action for example says: "[vuex] unknown action type: getMembers" Any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

The store is initialized twice with `new Vuex.Store`, the constructor is provided with store instance the second time, this results in a bug.

It's *store* that is exported from store.js, not *store data*.

It can be:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
});

export default store;
```

Then it's clear that it's store instance that is exported from store.js.

`Vue.use(Vuex)` is also called twice, this likely won't cause problems except a warning because Vue plugins usually contain a safeguard against multiple initialization. store.js doesn't need to contain it, it's common to initialize plugins in application entry point.

This is a potential mistake:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

import Vuex from "vuex";
...
```

Imports are hoisted according to specs, this behaviour is setup-dependent but it shouldn't be expected that this code will be evaluated in this order.

Needs to be:

```
import './bootstrap';
import Vue from "vue";    
import Vuex from "vuex";
import store from "./store";

window.Vue = Vue;
...
```