# Is there a way to add Vuex to Vue plugin install function and share state between its components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Basically i want to use my own store inside vue install and vue components i add throught my vue plugin.

I found that i can use vuex inside actual install function and do everything vuex can, but i can't seem to pass it to my custom components.

Is there any other ways to add global events in my SFC's that i add inside my plugin?

```js
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue'
import MySecondComponentfrom './MySecondComponent.vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import store from './store.js'

const CustomFn = function(message, options) {
    this.$store.dispatch("someRandomAction", { message, options })
}

export default {
    install(Vue, options) {
        if (this.installed) { return }
        this.installed = true

        Vue.use(Vuex)

        const storeInstance = new Vuex.Store(store)

        Vue['store'] = storeInstance

        // is there a way to add storeInstance to my own components and share one state between them?
        Vue.component('MyComponent', Vue.extend(MyComponent))
        Vue.component('MySecondComponent', Vue.extend(MySecondComponent))

        Vue.prototype['$doStuff'] = CustomFn
        Vue['doStuff'] = CustomFn
    }
}
```

Problem is that I cannot pass this Vuex store instance inside MyComponent and share the same store between multiple components.

Comment: `Vue.prototype['$doStuff'] =` - this is how it's done. Not `Vue['store'] =`. Is there some problem with that?

Comment: @EstusFlask the `$doStuff` method has little to do with wanting to add a store, problem is that i cannot share same store instance inside MyComponent

Comment: I mean that if you want it to be accessed as `this.store`, you need to assign it to `Vue.prototype.store`, the same way as you did for $doStuff

Comment: @EstusFlask yea but that doesnt work, store is initialized and there is no actions, no mutation, no state, no getters, its empty, even though I initialize it with storeObject

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. I'm quite sure you mixed different problems together. Vue.prototype.store just provides a value to instances, it doesn't matter whether it a function or store object. If a value was messed up, it will be. It's very likely that `store` is really a store and not store options as it would be expected from a module that's called `store`, so wrapping it with another store like new Vuex.Store(store) would be a mistake

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you for pushing me to do mcve because I found my problem, its because if I use Vuex store inside my plugin it add's it globally and if I define new store in my app it re-defines my store, so I have to export the store object and use it as a module

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-pare-04l07?file=/src/main.js

Comment: @EstusFlask next question is how i incapsulate Vuex inside a plugin.

Comment: @EstusFlask you can post `Vue.prototype.$store = storeInstance;` as an answer since it was the piece I was missing and is basically answer to my question on how to add store to vue plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom component properties are supposed to be globally provided in Vue 2 by assigning them to `Vue.prototype` because component instances prototypically inherit from it.

`new Vuex.Store(store)` is a mistake if `store` is already Vuex store and not plain object that contains store options. This will result in malfunctioning store like shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69967230/3731501). Even if `store` is not store instance yet, it makes sense to make it an instance and export in a separate module so it could be imported in non-component modules.

It should be:

```
Vue.prototype.$store = store
```